# Energy Stored in Electromagnetic field using Lagrangian formalism

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, energy, lagrangian-formalism, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

How to we get to

$$    \int(  (ɛ/2)E.E + (1/2μ)B.B ) d^{3}x $$

as the energy stored in electromagnetic field, while using the Lagrangian formalism of maxwell theory.

Comment: Use the LaTeX-like formulas like in LaTeX: encapsulated with `$$` for example.

Comment: You compute the (symmetric) stress-energy tensor and take the time-time component. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor). To see how to compute it, check any of the standard books in electrodynamics, like Jackson's.